Electron/Electron Builder get info about binary
We are distributing our Electron app for Macs using Intel and also Apple Silicon. We are using electron-builder.
I need a way to know if a user on Apple Silicon has accidentally installed the Intel version of the app.
Currently I'm able to get the platform and architecture of the system.
But how can I get the architecture that the .dmg file was built for?
I thought "process.target_arch" would be it but it is always undefined.
 Electron: ${process.versions["electron"]}
    Node: ${process.versions["node"]}
    Chromium: ${process.versions["chrome"]}
    Platform: ${os.platform}
    Architecture: ${os.arch}
    Target Arch: ${process?.target_arch}
    OS Version: ${process.getSystemVersion()}

